# Calculating the frequency of a recessive allele in case of three segregating alleles

Tags: genetics, hardy-weinberg

Is it correct to say:

**A.**  **f(A) = p; f(a) = q** 

**B.**  **p = f(AA) + ½ f(Aa)=$\sqrt{f(AA)}$**?

Also,

> For a gene locus segregating more than two alleles, the frequency of
>   each allele is the frequency of its homozygote plus 1/2 the sum of the
>   frequencies of all heterozygotes in which it can occur.

For example, I have this data on blood-types from a population: 42,4% type A, 8.3% type B, 1.4% type AB, 47.9% type O. Plus we know that p(A)=0.250, p(B)=0,050, p(O)=0,692. 
When I try to calculate p(O) in different ways, I get **p(O)= $\sqrt{0.479}$=0,692** 
If I calculate p(O) as:**p(O)= 0.479+½*0.424+½*0,083=0,7325**

 As the result, I am getting two different frequencies for p(O). What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Biology.SE

**A few issues about your post**

You should always limit your post to a single question.

Make sure to define what the function `f()` and `p()` mean.

Use points (`.`) instead of comas (`,`) for the numbers.

You should show how you made your calculations otherwise we can't tell what is right and wrong.

**Your question**

> is $p = f(AA) + \frac1{1}{2} f(Aa)=\sqrt{f(AA)}$ correct?

$$f(AA) = p^2$$
$$f(Aa) = 2pq = 2p(1-p)$$
$$f(Aa)/2 = pq = p(1-p) = p - p^2$$
, therefore

$$f(AA) + f(Aa)/2 = p^2 + (p - p^2) = p = \sqrt{p^2} = \sqrt{f(AA)}$$

So, yes you are correct